# Share different screenshots in other countries on App Store

Tags: app-store-connect, google-play-console

My app is live on Appstore and Google Play Store. This is what I want. Except other countries where I have my app. I want to share with different screenshots. For example, my current country is Turkey and my screenshots are in Turkish. I want the screenshots to be in english in other regions. For this, I set up a special store entry in GooglePlaystore. But I can't find how to do it in Appstore.

Answer (score 0):

This will need a new update on App Store.

- Make new update
- Then from `Prepare for submissions` tab go the language menu on the right and scroll down to "not localized" languages and choose English (*see the image below*)

[image]